# No matching function for call to a function that adds two linked list

Tags: c++

I have been solving a LeetCode (addTwoNumbers) problem in my local machine using XCode. The problem I am facing is when I call the function (addTwo) from the main function, there is an error:

> No matching function for call 'addTwo'

The issue is not how to address the LeetCode problem. The issue is when I want to develop a solution in my local machine having to include libraries, and using the STL to define `forward_list` I want to use to test my solution.

Can someone please advise how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <forward_list>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode{
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};
ListNode* addTwo(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2){
    ListNode* head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* current = head;
    
    int carry = 0;
    while(l1 || l2){
        int sum = carry;
        if(l1){
            sum += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if(l2){
            sum += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        int value = sum % 10;
        current->next = new ListNode(value);
        current = current->next;
        carry = sum / 10;

    }
    if (carry > 0){
        current->next = new ListNode(carry);
        current = current->next;
    }
   
    return head->next;
}

int main(){
    forward_list<int> l1 {1,2,3,4,5};
    forward_list<int> l2 {4,6,8};
    
    cout<<addTwo(l1, l2)<<endl; // here is the problem - NO matching function for 'addTwo'
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `addTwo()` takes two `ListNode*`s where you are passing two `std::forward_list` objects. You need to create two linked lists which have nodes that are of type `ListNode` and pass their heads to `addTwo()`

Comment: You can't use `forward_list<int>` to test your solution. You need to build lists of the type you defined. It's not difficult, just keep them short and systematic, not long and arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You must fill this template code, it is given on the problem page

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        
    }
};
```

So, the solution with your code is the following:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode* current = head;

        int carry = 0;
        while(l1 || l2){
            int sum = carry;
            if(l1){
                sum += l1->val;
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
            if(l2){
                sum += l2->val;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            int value = sum % 10;
            current->next = new ListNode(value);
            current = current->next;
            carry = sum / 10;

        }
        if (carry > 0){
            current->next = new ListNode(carry);
            current = current->next;
        }

        return head->next;
    }
};
```